# how to hide content on index page and show this when a post is opened?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I use WordPress.

my idea exactly look like [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).
i want on index page content doesn't show but when opeded post content's will be shown, like [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)

```
<article id="container">
<?php if(have_posts()):?> <?php while(have_posts()): the_post();?>
    
    <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_id(); ?>">
        
        <div class="postmetadata small-font">
            <ul>
                <li><?php bawpvc_views_sc('post_view', 'bawpvc_views_sc'); ?></li>
                <li><?php comments_popup_link();?></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        
        <div class="post-header">
        
            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </div><br />
        
        <div class="date small-font">
            <ul>
                <li><?php the_author()." " ;?></li>
                <li><?php the_modified_date();?></li>
                <li><?php the_category(', '." ")?></li>
                
            </ul>
        </div>  
        
    </div>
    
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

with the_content() :
[image]

with the_excerpt() :
[image]

but i want the content doesn't show.

Comment: what do you mean by hide content on index page? is it meaning: showing only titles? Also, the code you posted, is it from index.php or single.php?

Comment: yes shiwing only titles on  main page... and when clicked on any post showing title and content like stackoverflow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create two pages **1-index.php 2-single.php**

**index.php**

```
<?php if(have_posts()):?> <?php while(have_posts()): the_post();?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**single.php**

```
<?php if(have_posts()):?> <?php while(have_posts()): the_post();?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<br>
<?php the_content();?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

I thing that you mean the more tag? It can be used to truncate text on the homepage and in the archive:
http://en.support.wordpress.com/splitting-content/more-tag/